# How to make method which is in other method?

Tags: java, android

```
public void drawEverything(Canvas canvas) {
....

}
```

I want to make a method that can use `canvas`.
Question 1. Can I make a method in drawEverything()?
Question 2. How can I solve this?

Comment: Why don't you just pass it to the ```drawMacro(Canvas canvas)``` method?

Comment: What's the context of drawMacro? By the looks of things, you'll want to use a lambda or you should question it being a function at all, depending.

Comment: You can't define a method inside another method. What are you trying to do with this `canvas` that you need another method? If you explained what you're trying to do maybe someone can suggest a solution that does work.

Comment: "What are you trying to do with this canvas that you need another method?" because I already have structure and I don't know how it works

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!!!!

```
pubilc class outterClass {
public void drawMacro(Canvas canvas, .....) {
}
public void drawEveryThing(Canvas canvas) {
....
drawMacro(canvas, ....);
...
}
}
```

Thank you for your advice!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean exactly.
If you want to use canvas in drawMacro it is impossible because canvas is just a parameter.
If you can describe your question in detail, I may give your better advice.
May it helps, best regard.

Comment: you can put this in the comment section as its not a solution yet.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I changed the question.